# Square and round brackets operator, how to choose overloads?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I want to access to some class data using `operator[]` but depending on the index type into the square brackets return one kind of data or other. As a simplified example:

```
struct S
{
    int   &operator []( int index ) { std::cout << "[i]"; return i_buffer[index]; }
    short &operator [](short index) { std::cout << "[s]"; return s_buffer[index]; }

private:
    int   i_buffer[10]{ 0,  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9  };
    short s_buffer[10]{ 0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999 };
};
```

There's no way to write a `short` literal, so the only way to choose the `short` overload is by casting:

```
S s;
std::cout << s[9] << '\n';        // prints [i]9
std::cout << s[(short)9] << '\n'; // prints [s]999
```

But I don't like it and I was wondering if there's different options.

### What I've tried?

#### *Tagged* parameter.

First I've tried to use "*tags*":

```
struct S
{
    enum class i_type : std::int32_t {};
    enum class s_type : std::int32_t {};

    int   &operator [](i_type index)
    { std::cout << "[i]"; return i_buffer[static_cast<int>(index)]; }
    short &operator [](s_type index)
    { std::cout << "[s]"; return s_buffer[static_cast<int>(index)]; }

private:
    int   i_buffer[10]{ 0,  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9  };
    short s_buffer[10]{ 0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999 };
};
```

That works but is still a little verbose:

```
S s;
std::cout << s[9] << '\n';            // error, no possible overload to be taken
std::cout << s[S::i_type{9}] << '\n'; // prints [i]9
std::cout << s[S::s_type{9}] << '\n'; // prints [s]999
```

#### Template.

As a crazy workaround I wanted to try to template the operator:

```
struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    T &operator [](T) { std::cout << "???"; return 0; }

private:
    int   i_buffer[10]{ 0,  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9  };
    short s_buffer[10]{ 0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999 };
};

template <>
int   &S::operator [](int index)   { std::cout << "[i]"; return i_buffer[index]; }
template <>
short &S::operator [](short index) { std::cout << "[s]"; return s_buffer[index]; }
```

The template version behaves as the original code, but there's no easy way to specify a type parameter along with the `operator[]`:

```
S s;
std::cout << s[9] << '\n';        // prints [i]9 like before
std::cout << s[(short)9] << '\n'; // prints [s]999 like before
std::cout << s<short>[9] << '\n'; // s is not template
std::cout << s[9]<short> << '\n'; // nonsense
// Correct but utterly verbose and hard to write and read
std::cout << s.operator[]<short>(9) << '\n';
```

#### Question.

All the issues described also happens with `operator()`, I want to know if there's more alternatives that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Make `i_buffer` and `s_buffer` public as `i` and `s` =] (But really, something to that effect might suit your needs.)

Comment: While this is an interesting exercise, it is my view that method names should express intent. `operator[]` naturally expresses the intent of 'indexing into some container'. To modify that indent based on the exact type of the argument seems to be something that will 'surprise' users of your class, and lead to code whose intent cannot be determined by a cursory reading. I think this is an error.

Comment: @Richard Hodges, `s/indent/intent`

Comment: once you return a (non-const) reference to internal data, the data isnt private anymore in any practical sense. So I compeltely agree with @Ryan: simply make it public

Comment: @7stud fixed, thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `S` structure? What is the original and actual problem you want to solve with your solution? Maybe it would be wiser to ask about that problem instead? This seems like [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: @RichardHodges as I said this is a simplified example; my use case is a matrix which can be accessed by columns or rows. I can use methods `m.row(0)[0]`, `m.column(0)[0]` but I like the double bracket syntax: `m[column{0}][0]`, `m[row{0}][0]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude take a look to my previous comment :)

Comment: `m[column{0}]` is unnecessarily fancy. Definitely stick with `m.column(0)` or `m.columns[0]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that using a *named method* is a much better idea than using `operator[]` in your situation, as it would be easier to understand that two separate buffers are being accessed by reading the source code.

Regardless, if you want to use your `operator[]` approach, you could use [**strong typedefs**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html) and [**user defined literals**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) to have type-safety with minimal syntactic overhead:

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(std::size_t, int_index)
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(std::size_t, short_index)

struct S
{
    auto& operator[](int_index i) { /* ... */ }
    auto& operator[](short_index i) { /* ... */ }
};

auto operator "" _ii(unsigned long long int x) { return int_index{x}; }
auto operator "" _si(unsigned long long int x) { return short_index{x}; }
```

You can then call your methods as follows:

```
S s;

auto& some_int = s[15_ii];
auto& some_short = s[4_si];
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DGp5srl61GvlBTa5)

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd use `std::tie` from the `<tuple>` library and then write a little helper to find the correct reference type:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

template<class As, class...Ts>
auto& as(std::tuple<const Ts&...>ts)
{
    return std::get<As const&>(ts);
};

template<class As, class...Ts>
auto& as(std::tuple<Ts&...>ts)
{
    return std::get<As &>(ts);
};

struct S
{
    // both cost and mutable version provided for completeness.

    auto operator[](std::size_t i) const {
        return std::tie(i_buffer[i], s_buffer[i]);
    }

    auto operator[](std::size_t i) {
        return std::tie(i_buffer[i], s_buffer[i]);
    }

private:
    int   i_buffer[10]{ 0,  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9  };
    short s_buffer[10]{ 0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999 };
};

int main()
{
    auto s = S();
    const auto x = S();

    std::cout << "short is : " << as<short>(s[5])<< '\n';
    std::cout << "int is : " << as<int>(s[5])<< '\n';

    std::cout << "short is : " << as<short>(x[6])<< '\n';
    std::cout << "int is : " << as<int>(x[6])<< '\n';
}
```

This way, the code is explicit but still succinct.

expected output:

```
short is : 555
int is : 5
short is : 666
int is : 6
```

Having read the further comments, I might choose to store the matrix in (say) row-wise form and then provide a col-wise wrapper.

A barely functional example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>


template<std::size_t Rows, std::size_t Cols>
struct RowWiseMatrix
{

    auto& operator[](std::size_t i) { return data_[i]; }

    std::array<std::array<double, Cols>, Rows> data_;
};

template<std::size_t Rows, std::size_t Cols>
struct ColumnProxy
{
    ColumnProxy(std::array<std::array<double, Cols>, Rows>& data, std::size_t col)
            : data_(data), col_(col)
    {

    }

    auto& operator[](std::size_t i) { return data_[i][col_]; }

    std::array<std::array<double, Cols>, Rows>& data_;
    std::size_t col_;
};


template<std::size_t Rows, std::size_t Cols>
struct ColWiseProxy
{
    ColWiseProxy(RowWiseMatrix<Rows, Cols>& mat) : underlying_(mat) {}

    auto operator[](std::size_t i) { return ColumnProxy<Rows, Cols> { underlying_.data_, i }; }

    RowWiseMatrix<Rows, Cols>& underlying_;
};


template<std::size_t Rows, std::size_t Cols>
auto& rowWise(RowWiseMatrix<Rows, Cols>& mat)
{
    return mat;
};

template<std::size_t Rows, std::size_t Cols>
auto colWise(RowWiseMatrix<Rows, Cols>& mat)
{
    return ColWiseProxy<Rows, Cols>(mat);
};

int main()
{
    auto m = RowWiseMatrix<3, 3> {
            std::array<double, 3>{ 1, 2, 3 },
            std::array<double, 3>{ 4, 5, 6},
            std::array<double, 3>{ 7, 8, 9}
    };

    std::cout << rowWise(m)[0][2] << '\n';
    std::cout << colWise(m)[0][2] << '\n';
}
```

Expected output:

```
3
7
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Vittorio Romeo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41849786/2805305) that the best solution is a named method.

However here is a solution:

```
template <class T> struct S_proxy {
  T* data; 
  T& operator[](std::size_t i) { return data[i]; }
};

struct S
{
    auto i_type() { return S_proxy<int>{i_buffer}; };
    auto s_type() { return S_proxy<short>{s_buffer}; };

private:
    int   i_buffer[10]{ 0,  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9  };
    short s_buffer[10]{ 0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999 };
};
```

and use:

```
S s;
return s.s_type()[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

If i_type and s_type are supposed to have a meaning by themselves, it is possible to add semantics to operators []. Something like

```
#include <iostream>

struct Month {
    explicit Month(int m)
        : m(m)
    {
    }
    int m;
};

struct Day {
    explicit Day(short d)
        : d(d)
    {
    }
    short d;
};

struct S {
    int& operator[](const Month& mes)
    {
        std::cout << "[i]";
        return i_bufer[mes.m];
    }
    short& operator[](const Day& dis)
    {
        std::cout << "[s]";
        return s_bufer[dis.d];
    }

private:
    int i_bufer[10]{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    short s_bufer[10]{ 0, 111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888, 999 };
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    std::cout << s[Month(9)] << '\n'; // muestra [i]9
    std::cout << s[Day(9)] << '\n'; // muestra [s]999
}
```

Comment: That's indeed what I did in the "***Tagged* parameter**" approach.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster I don't think so, they looks similar, but their meanings are conceptually different.

Comment: You used a `struct`, I've used an inner `enum class`, exact same behaviour but different approach.

Comment: Well, in my example, `Month` and `Day` can have behaviour, constraints, states; they can have meaning beyond their names, they can have their own external references to actual facts; not the case for enums, in my opinion.

Comment: I don't see the difference between using `struct` to disambiguate calls and using an `enum class` for the same goal. Both approaches uses a different type in order to disambiguate calls. Is there something I'm missing? Just note that my **only** goal is disambiguate calls, not to add any kind of behaviour.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Well, if your **only** goal is calls disambiguation, any of the approaches, while correct, are equivalent.

Comment: That's it. I never said that you were wrong, only that you tried something I've already tried myself.